# restrict collection.find() should only return non-empty object but not empty objects inside array

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
const response = await simpleSurveyResponsesModel
        .find({
          "metaKey.projectId": 7,
        })
        .select([
          "answers.SEC.text",
          "answers.S4.text",
          "answers.S3_a.text",
          "answers.Urban_City.text"
        ])
        .lean();
```

Where answers feild is array of objects containing both empty ad non-empty objects.

collection.find() returns the selected objects but also empty objects as well, inside answers array which i dont need.

**My Output**

```
{
    "_id": "61840979fcbea215bc61ed03",
    "answers": [
        {},
        {},
        {
            "Urban_City": {
                "text": "Hyderabad"
            }
        },
    ]
 }
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
    "_id": "61840979fcbea215bc61ed03",
    "answers": [
        {
            "Urban_City": {
                "text": "Hyderabad"
            }
        },
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried Array.filter?

Comment: Yes i am already using array.filter but i need some way where mongo query itself help me out to get rid of these empty array objects. Doing so will help me in the result speed and optimisation.

Comment: You might try aggregation with `$filter`.  I'd be curious to see if it performs any better.